# Thread block based on input of a function

Tags: java, thread-safety

I got in situation where I have to synchronized function based on input. for example. There is function.
func(int a)--- this function can be called by many threads I want to block threads if they are trying to call this function with the same input integer. Otherwise let them continue without continue. I wrote function

```
HashTable<Integer> check=new Hashtable<Integer>();

func(int a){

Integer lock=check.get(a);
if(lock==null){
check.put(a);
}else{
check.put(a);
}
synchronized(lock){
//do something....
```

}
  }

Please let me know if this is right. Also if there is any other solution other than this. I am trying to figure out. If I find answer I will post it.

Comment: This is not going to work: it's possible for two threads to request a non-existent integer from the table prior to either one putting the number into the table. You need some kind of synchronization around getting/putting the number into the table to avoid race conditions like that.

Comment: You also need to make the code compile. You need synchronization, or you can also se a ConcurrentHashMap and its putIfAbsent() method. @dlev: you should make that an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) getting a lock should be in a synchronized block too

2) there's a memory leak - you do not remove unused locks

I would do it this way

```
Map<Integer, Lock> map = new HashMap<>();

static class Lock {
    int count = 1;
}

void func(int i) {
    Object lock = getLock(i);
    try {
        synchronized (lock) {
            //
        }
    } finally {
        releaseLock(i);
    }
}

private synchronized Object getLock(int i) {
    Lock lock = map.get(i);
    if (lock != null) {
        lock.count++;
    } else {
        lock = new Lock();
        map.put(i, lock);
    }
    return lock;
}

private synchronized void releaseLock(int i) {
    Lock lock = map.get(i);
    if (--lock.count == 0) {
        map.remove(i);   
    }
}
```